# How to pass texify tex options?

Tags: pdftex, vim, vim-latex, texify

TLDR: I need to pass `-file-line-error-style` option to texify. I don't know how :(

I use vim-latex and I want to tweak it to use texify instead of pdflatex since this is the engine that TeXWorks uses. However, I want to be able to pass `-file-line-error-style` option to see the possible errors. The manual says I can use `--tex-option=option`, but I don't know how it works. Should I put the option in quotes?

Any help is appreciated.